# Is it possible that the popular applications in my laptop are surveilling my files on hard drive?

Tags: security

What if I develop a desktop application which million people will use, and behind the scene, the application is surveilling users' files on their hard drives, streaming the data time to time? 
Can one be assured no such things happen, with any popular software applications, be it MS Office or Google Chrome?
Or this is just a stupid question?

Comment: There is a thing called `auditing of the applicatio` which detects these kinds of data-thefts!

Comment: One can be assured, and it's called Open Source where you can have the option to search the source code for such intricate parts of the code. Closed-source apps have a much higher chance of better hiding what they're doing. That's why we like Open Source more, among other reasons. Large companies usually implement network packet scanning to protect from such potential problems, so as you can see - there are ways to be evil and there are ways to combat the evil. If you are developing potentially popular desktop app - don't be evil. It never pays off in the long run.

Comment: Of course it's possible.  That's why your package manager will only install packages signed by your distro (you do have to have some trust in the package maintainers; if not, you need to build everything yourself after reading - and understanding - every line of the code).

Comment: @Mjh, open source does not solve this. It creates higher barriers, but it is no assurance. In practice it is not possible to fully audit open source (OpenSSL has a long and tortured history of significant bugs, at least one of which may have been intentionally introduced). Even if you can audit, there is the famous Ken Thompson attack. http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/04/15/strange-loops-dennis-ritchie-a/ Open source provides certain benefits, but it is no panacea. This is not a solvable problem. Having worked in large company InfoSec, we did not have the kind of scanning you describe.

Comment: @RobNapier I wrote **one can have the option**. I never said it's a trivial task to do so. Also, I'm working for a client right now that scans every single thing that goes through their network. If you haven't done or seen something, it doesn't mean other people don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it technically possible? Yes, it is.
Could it be happening in an application used by a million users for a relatively long time without being noticed? Very unlikely. Somebody would notice the strange network traffic eventually.

Also @Mjh mentioned open source in a comment. While open source can help by allowing people to audit the source code, how many times have you checked that the binary you are using is actually the compiled source that you were looking at? Of course, there are signatures on binary packages and all, but the signature is made by the package maintainer. There is an inherent trust not only in the developer of the application, but also in the tool chain that creates a binary package from the source code. And then we haven't talked about strange ["bugs"](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/), or the fact that even in open source, some security issues are very hard to find (otherwise all open source software would be security bug-free, which they are not).

So back to your question, sure, you could use all kinds of techniques to monitor the behavior of an application, you could monitor memory access, network traffic, whatever else. You can also analyse the code itself, look for suspicious things. It will take a huge amount of effort and still there will be no 100% guarantee, only some level of assurance.

Automated version upgrades could make detection even harder by the way. Even if you put lots of resources into analysis of one version, what if only a short-lived version had malicious code? Sure, that too can be analysed, but would anyone bother, unless there was a good reason (like indications of something malicious)?

Yet I think you can be pretty sure that major vendors don't do this. It's just not worth it for them, why would they? Their risk would be huge, with a relatively low benefit.

Comment: It would be great if we can customize file access permission up to application level, which is currently at user level.